# Дружба — это никак неотъемлемая / не отъемлемая часть жизни

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Дружба — это никак неотъемлемая / не отъемлемая часть жизни.

Comment: А разве есть слово _отъемлемый_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Дружба — это **совершено неотъемлемая** часть жизни.*

Слово не употребляется без НЕ, поэтому пишется всегда слитно. Нужно использовать наречие степени для **усиления** утверждения.